# Copy the attributes of one template's parameter into another

Tags: xslt

In XSLT 1.0, I want to copy the parameter of one template into the parameter of another template. Similar to a global variable.

Template uiButton is called from another file and provides functionality similar to an html title attribute:

```
<xsl:call-template name="uiButton">
    <xsl:with-param name="uiButton_title">Rollover Title Attribute</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

I would like to copy the parameter of uiButton into this new template, drawNavItem as not to repeat the code. Can I do something like this?

```
<xsl:template name="drawNavItem">
    <xsl:param name="title">
        <xsl:call-template name="uiButton">
            <xsl:with-param name="uiButton_title">Rollover Title Attribute</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:param>
</xsl:template>
```

The expected outcome should have the title parameter below copy the functionality from uiButton:

```
<xsl:call-template name="drawNavItem">
    <xsl:with-param name="title">Rollover Title Attribute</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: It might be that in XSLT 2 and 3 tunnel parameters https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#tunnel-params help you but I am not quite sure I have understood what you want, you haven't provided minimal but complete samples of XML you have, XSLT you have together with the current and the wanted result.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I am limited to XSLT 1.0. The tunnel parameters would have been helpful. Is there another way to treat one parameter like a global variable? I have updated my post and tried to add an example of what I hope makes sense.

Comment: It is possible to call a template to populate the default value of a parameter, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#variables, so the snippet you have shown after your "Can I do something like this?" is something that is allowed. It would set the default value of the parameter named `title` to the result returned by the `call-template` call.